# User with a membership can read all data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, cancancan

## The Setup

I'm using Rails 5.2 with the [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem.

```
rails g scaffold User first_name email:uniq
rails g scaffold Organization name:uniq
rails g scaffold Role name
rails g scaffold Membership user:references organization:references role:refences
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :roles, through: :memberships
  has_many :organizations, through: :memberships
end
```

**membership.rb**

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**organization.rb**

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

**role.rb**

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

**seeds.rb**

```
admin = Role.create(name: 'Admin')
user = Role.create(name: 'User')

abc = Organization.create(name: 'Abc Inc.')

bob = User.create(first_name: 'Bob')
alice = User.create(first_name: 'Alice')

Membership.create(role: user, company: abc, role: user)
Membership.create(role: admin, company: abc, role: admin)
```

## The Task

An admin should be able to manage all users and memberships of the company he/she is admin for. A user can only read all users and memberships of that company.

Here is my take on a cancancan configuration:

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    user_role = Role.find_by_name('User')
    admin_role = Role.find_by_name('Admin')

    organizations_with_user_role = Organization.includes(:memberships).
      where(memberships: {user_id: user.id, role_id: user_role.id})
    organizations_with_admin_role = Organization.includes(:memberships).
      where(memberships: {user_id: user.id, role_id: admin_role.id})

    can :read, Organization, organizations_with_user_role
    can :manage, Organization, organizations_with_admin_role
  end
end
```

Then I try to run this code in a view:

```
<% if can? :read, organization %><%= link_to 'Show', organization %><% end %>
```

This results with an error page which says:

*The can? and cannot? call cannot be used with a raw sql 'can' definition. The checking code cannot be determined for :read #*

I guess I'm tackling the problem from a totally wrong angle. How do I have to setup the `ability.rb` to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities):

> Almost anything that you can pass to a hash of conditions in Active
>   Record will work here. The only exception is working with model ids.
>   You can't pass in the model objects directly, you must pass in the
>   ids.
>
> ```
> can :manage, Project, group: { id: user.group_ids }
> ```

So try something like:

```
can :read, Organization, id: organizations_with_user_role.pluck(:id)
```

On a separate note, why are you using `includes` instead of `joins`? Your query can be simplified to (without the need for `user_role = Role.find_by_name('User')`):

```
organizations_with_user_role = Organization.joins(memberships: :role).
  where(memberships: {user_id: user.id}).where(roles: {name: 'User'})
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a simple hash of conditions here:

```
can :read, Organization, memberships: { user_id: user.id, role: { name: 'User' } }
can :manage, Organization, memberships: { user_id: user.id, role: { name: 'Admin' } }
```

this should be really enough and you have the advantage that, with this syntax, you can also call Organization.accessible_by(ability, :read) and retrieve all the Organizations that a user can read.